# Django convert raw SQL query to Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am using Django Rest Framework and I have this query in raw SQL but I want to do it in the Django ORM instead.
I have tried using the different Django tools but so far it has not given me the expected result.

```
select tt.id, tt.team_id, tt.team_role_id, tt.user_id  from task_teammember tt 
inner join task_projectteam tp on tp.team_id = tt.team_id 
where tp.project_id = 1
```

models

```
class TeamMember(models.Model):
    user       = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team       = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team_role  = models.ForeignKey(TeamRole,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state      = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)


class ProjectTeam(models.Model):
    project    = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    team       = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    state      = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `project` object already then this should get you what I believe you want. Your `TeamMember` model has access to `Team`, which links to `ProjectTeam`, and to `Project` - the double-underscore accessor navigates through the relationships.

```py
TeamMember.objects.filter(team__projectteam__project=project)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would advise to span a `ManyToManyField` over the `ProjectTeam`, this will make queries simpler:

```
from django.conf import settings


class TeamMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # …

class Team(models.Model):
    projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, through='ProjectTeam')
    # …


class ProjectTeam(models.Model):
    # …
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Then you can easily filter with:

```
TeamMember.objects.filter(team__projects=project_id)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when updating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's goes like:

```
TeamMember.objects.filter(team__projectteam__project__id=1)
```

Django orm allow reverse foreginkey lookup